# How to import python file from a parent folder?

Tags: python, import, parent

I have a directory folder:
MainFolder : [ folder1 : (file1.py), folder2 : (file2.py) ]
I'm writing a program in file2.py, which needs to import the code from file1.py.
Is there a way to do that?
I tried this:`from .. import folder1.file1.py` Can somebody explain what I am supposed to do here?
`

Answer (score 0):

To use `from` yo have to put the directory and `import` the file without the .py

```
from folder import file
```

Try this.